# Shortest way to find if a string matchs an object's attribute value in a list of objects of that type in Python

Tags: algorithm, python

I have a list with objects of x type. Those objects have an attribute name. 
I want to find if a string matchs any of those object names. If I would have a list with the object names I just would do  `if string in list`, so I was wondering given the current situation if there is a way to do it without having to loop over the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another

```
dict( (o.name,o) for o in obj_list )[name]
```

The trick, though, is avoid creating a list `obj_list` in the first place.

Since you know that you're going to fetch objects by the string value of an attribute, do not use a list, use a dictionary instead of a list.

A dictionary can be trivially "searched" for matching strings.  It's a better choice than a list.

Comment: it works if he would have the name attribute as a key, but when multiple objects have same name it only gives the last in array..
but good one.. +1

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Ahmad Dwaik. I didnt mention it in my question, but the object names are unique, meaning S.Lott answer is my case

Answer (score 5):

```
any(obj for obj in objs if obj.name==name)
```

Note, that it will stop looping after first match found.

Answer (score 4):

What do you want to do if the string matches?  Do you just want to return True/False, or return a list of objects that match?
To return a boolean:

```
any(obj.name == name for obj in objs)
```

(I find this slightly more readable than Denis Otkidach's version).

to filter the list:

```
[obj for obj in objs if obj.name == name]
```

Comment: I want to return true or false. it's to stop an infinite recursion

Answer (score 1):

if string in [x.name for x in list_of_x]

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in listOfItemsOfTypeX:
    if i.name == myString: return True
return False
```